# Police succeeded in tracking 7% of stolen bicycles

Tags: probability, statistics

Police succeeded in tracking 7% of stolen bicycles. 
a.) Approximately 1600 bikes are stolen in one city area per year. What is the the probability that the police will succeed in tracing more than 100 stolen bicycles?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. In the future, please avoid posting a question without explaining what you have tried. This site is meant to promote learning; it is not meant to be a place where you dump problems to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binomial model would be appropriate. Let $X$ be the number of stolen bicycles that are tracked. Then $X\sim B(1600,0.07)$. You can then compute $$P(X>100)=1-P(X\leq 100)=1-0.1290=\fbox{0.8710} \text{ (to 4d.p.)}$$